# XGboost Google-AI-Model expecting float values instead of using Categorical values and converting them

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm trying to run a simple XGBoost Prediction based on Google Cloud using this simple example https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/getting-predictions-xgboost#get_online_predictions

The model is building fine, but when I try to run a prediction with a sample input JSON it fails with error "Could not initialize DMatrix from inputs: **could not convert string to float**:" as shown in the screen below. I understand this is happening because the test-input has strings, I was hoping the Google machine learning model should have information to convert the categorical values to floats. I cannot expect my user to submit-online-prediction-request with float values.

Based on the tutorial it should work without converting the categorical values to floats. Please advise, I have attached the GIF with more details. Thanks

[image]

```
import json
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# these are the column labels from the census data files
COLUMNS = (
    'age',
    'workclass',
    'fnlwgt',
    'education',
    'education-num',
    'marital-status',
    'occupation',
    'relationship',
    'race',
    'sex',
    'capital-gain',
    'capital-loss',
    'hours-per-week',
    'native-country',
    'income-level'
)

# categorical columns contain data that need to be turned into numerical
# values before being used by XGBoost
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = (
    'workclass',
    'education',
    'marital-status',
    'occupation',
    'relationship',
    'race',
    'sex',
    'native-country'
)

# load training set
with open('./census_data/adult.data', 'r') as train_data:
    raw_training_data = pd.read_csv(train_data, header=None, names=COLUMNS)
# remove column we are trying to predict ('income-level') from features list
train_features = raw_training_data.drop('income-level', axis=1)
# create training labels list
train_labels = (raw_training_data['income-level'] == ' >50K')


# load test set
with open('./census_data/adult.test', 'r') as test_data:
    raw_testing_data = pd.read_csv(test_data, names=COLUMNS, skiprows=1)
# remove column we are trying to predict ('income-level') from features list
test_features = raw_testing_data.drop('income-level', axis=1)
# create training labels list
test_labels = (raw_testing_data['income-level'] == ' >50K.')

# convert data in categorical columns to numerical values
encoders = {col:LabelEncoder() for col in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}
for col in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
    train_features[col] = encoders[col].fit_transform(train_features[col])
for col in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
    test_features[col] = encoders[col].fit_transform(test_features[col])

# load data into DMatrix object
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train_features, train_labels)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(test_features)

# train XGBoost model
bst = xgb.train({}, dtrain, 20)
bst.save_model('./model.bst')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fix. Put the input shown in the Google documentation in a file `input.json`, then run this. The output is `input_numerical.json` and prediction will succeed if you use that in place of `input.json`.

This code is just preprocessing categorical columns to numerical forms using the same procedure as was done with training and test data.

```
import json

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

COLUMNS = (
    "age",
    "workclass",
    "fnlwgt",
    "education",
    "education-num",
    "marital-status",
    "occupation",
    "relationship",
    "race",
    "sex",
    "capital-gain",
    "capital-loss",
    "hours-per-week",
    "native-country",
    "income-level",
)

# categorical columns contain data that need to be turned into numerical
# values before being used by XGBoost
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = (
    "workclass",
    "education",
    "marital-status",
    "occupation",
    "relationship",
    "race",
    "sex",
    "native-country",
)

with open("./input.json", "r") as json_lines:
    rows = [json.loads(line) for line in json_lines]

prediction_features = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=(COLUMNS[:-1]))

encoders = {col: LabelEncoder() for col in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}
for col in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
    prediction_features[col] = encoders[col].fit_transform(prediction_features[col])

with open("input_numerical.json", "w") as input_numerical:
    for index, row in prediction_features.iterrows():
        input_numerical.write(row.to_json(orient="values") + "\n")
```

I created [this Google Issues Tracker ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189593633) as the Google documentation is missing this important step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to convert categorical strings into codes for model inputs. For prediction input you can define a dictionary for each category with corresponding category values and codes. For example, for workclass:

```
df['workclass_cat'] = df['workclass'].astype('category')
df['workclass_cat'] = df['workclass_cat'].cat.codes
workclass_dict = dict(zip(list(df['workclass'].values), list(df['workclass_cat'].values)))
```

If a prediction input is 'somestring' you can access its code as follows:

```
category_input = workclass_dict['somestring']
```

Answer (score 0):

XGBoost models take floats as input. In your training script you converted the categorical variables into numbers. The same transformation needs to be done when submitting a prediction.